# headless_ie_selenium not working with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to change my code to use an [IE headless browser](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/blob/master/README.md). The automation I'm doing is in a website that only works in internet explorer

My code was working great until I tried to use a headless browser

When I run this code, absolutely nothing happens, no error is thrown

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Inicialização do Selenium
ie_options = Options()
ie_options.ignore_zoom_level = True

## WORKS!
# driver = webdriver.Ie(service=Service(IEDriverManager().install()), options=ie_options)

## NOT WORKING
service = Service(executable_path=constantes.PATH_HEADLESS)
driver = webdriver.Ie(service=service, options=ie_options)


# Acessa a página
driver.get(constantes.URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why it seems nothing is happening is because you have no output (not printing anything). I'm not familiar with your process, but I tried it out with mine also using chrome and it worked fine. Context:

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('*executable 
    path'),options=chrome_options)
    
    driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
    print(driver.title)
```

Comment: but i said I need to use Internet Explorer... And is not because I'm not printing anything, the code  does not continue execution

Comment: The difference is to change the driver, that's why i said "also". Will you consider trying a different process to troubleshoot where the problem is? Major difference is the headless declaration and i'm not familiar with yours but i got my results.